# Cloudflare Pending validation error due to VirusTotal

Tags: cdn, cloudflare, validation, virus

My domain (quảcầu.cc/xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc) couldn't receive certification due to an error:
[image]

When I checked with [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/70b25cdf4fafc7d16f402d688c189554d186a80dc223ec0c2aa4ca46c0015779/detection), only one security vendor flagged this URL as malicious. The rest flagged it clean.

[image]

I suppose this is a false positive. But how should I solve this?